# How to decode base64 encoded JSON in Go

Tags: json, string, go, base64

I have a map of type `map[string][]byte`, now the value of `[]byte` is base64 encoded.
There's a JSON encoded in that `[]byte` that I want to use further. Now I do this to decode the base64 `[]byte` array.

Assume that my `secretInfo` looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: my-credentials
data:
  secret_account.json: SGVsbG8sIHBsYXlncm91bmQ= // My base64 encoded data(not real/Actual data)
```

```
bytes, _ := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(secretInfo.Data["secret_account.json"])) // Converting data
var privateKeyJSON map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &privateKeyJSON)
if err != nil {
        r.Logger.Infof("Failed to parse secret %v", err)
    }
```

Now, I pass the value of the JSON to other JSON as a string.

```
secretInfo.StringData["DecodedPrivateKeyJson"] = string(bytes)
```

It throws me an error saying, expected JSON in StringData.DecodedPrivateKeyJson.

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like the encoded value is not a valid JSON. could you make sure of that?

Comment: @mehdy that is a dummy value, just assume that's a valid JSON. I cannot post the actual JSON as it has all the private encoded  JSON as it has lots of personal data. But rest assured, the JSON is encoded perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is some issue in your code above

1. You ignored the decode error
2. You have not provided the code for how you parse the secret info

Adding a sample code with few cases, Hope It Helps :)

package main

```
import (
    b64 "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    encodedJSONTestData := []string{
        "ewoiZmlyc3RuYW1lIjoiSmhvbiIsCiJsYXN0bmFtZSI6ICJEb2UiCn0=",
        "",
        "!@#$%rtgfdjkmyhm",
    }

    for i, encodedJSON := range encodedJSONTestData {
        fmt.Println("Case", i)
        bytes, err := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encodedJSON) // Converting data
        
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println("Failed to Decode secret", err)
            continue
        }
        
        var privateKeyJSON map[string]interface{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &privateKeyJSON)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to parse secret", err)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Println("Success", privateKeyJSON)
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ejVz1WgxysL)

[Updated same code to use []Byte to provide more clarity](http://play.golang.org/p/NNUkrdqV_Hp)

Comment: hey Shubham, if you look closely, my map which has the encoded value is of type `[]Byte`,  which is then encoded in `Base64`. Here you have declared `encodedJSONTestData` as it contains a `[]string` value and not `[]byte`.
Can you please fix that?.

Comment: @RajatSingh []string is for showing multiple cases, each case runs in loop so you can check how different values  affects output, As for []byte you convert them to string before passing to DecodeString so it is same thing

Comment: Can you join this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220485/discuss-on-golang-json

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```golang
secretInfo.StringData["DecodedPrivateKeyJson"] = string(bytes)
```

Which probably it should be like this:

```golang
secretInfo.StringData["DecodedPrivateKeyJson"] = string(privateKeyJSON)
```

Or event better:

```golang
marshaledPrivateKeyJSON, _ := json.Marshal(privateKeyJSON)
secretInfo.StringData["DecodedPrivateKeyJson"] = string(marshaledPrivateKeyJSON)
```